# Set WPF/XAML window client area size

Tags: wpf, xaml, forms, window

I have a pixel perfect control layout for a form I want to create. I know the exact width, height and location of each control.

But I am finding it difficult to set it perfectly inside a Window element.

The Width and Height property of the Window is including the borders. How can I set the inner width and height of the window? The Client width and height.

Say, my form is 300px wide. If I set the width and height of the Window to 300, then the borders take up anywhere from 5 - 15px and only 285 or so pixels are available for the client area where you can add controls. I want to set *this* client area's width to 300px.

I tried having a container control like a Grid or StackPanel and set its width to 300px and setting the window's widthto auto. But the window was way too wide.

Hope I am making sense.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach of setting an inner panel width and letting the window size itself accordingly is correct. What you probably might have missed is the property `SizeToContent` of the window. Set `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` and it will work.